Subproject build.gradle being overwritten or failing to generate files
Background Info
I am working on upgrading from Java 11 to Java 17, Gradle 6.8.x to 8.5, and from Spring Boot 2.x to 3.x.
The application has 3 build.gradle files with a core version and 2 subprojects.
One subproject (:api) is configured for use with OpenAPI and OpenAPI Generator, the other is for Test Generation (:test), but uses resources from the  :api subproject generate the tests dynamically using OpenAPI Generator.
The project originally was using OpenAPI 3.0.1, which I have pushed to 3.1.0. This was a godsend with the validating being more clear about errors.
The project was also using OpenAPI Generator 4.3.1, which I have updated to 7.8.0 (for both support with Spring Boot 3 and to resolve some breaking bugs).
Both the :test and :api subprojects' build.gradle files have an openApiGenerate task. They both share the spec.yaml file, but it belongs to the :api subproject.
The key difference I notated was the :api one is using Spring like so:
openApiGenerate {
  generatorName = "spring"
  inputSpec = "$swaggerSourceFile"
  outputDir = "$swaggerOutputDir"
  configFile = "$swaggerConfigFile"
  configOptions = [
    dateLibrary: "java8",
    useJakarta: "true",
    useSpringBoot3: "true"
  ]
}

And the :test subproject uses java, configured like so:
openApiGenerate {
  generatorName = "java"
  inputSpec = "$swaggerSourceFile"
  outputDir = "$swaggerOutputDir"
  configFile = "$swaggerConfigFile"
  configOptions = [
    dateLibrary: "java8",
    useJakarta: "true",
    useSpringBoot3: "true"
  ]
  library = "rest-assured"
}

The $swaggerSourceFile is the path to the :api subproject's spec.yaml based on relative pathing.
The $swaggerOutFir is just that subproject's directory defined using $projectDir
The $swaggerConfig file is the same 10 settings in both inside a config.json file. The key ones being:

useBeanValidation: true
useTags: true
performBeanValidation: true
implicitHeaders: true
interfaceOnly: true
java8: false // originally set as true

Issue 01
Upgrading to Gradle 8.5 caused it to ask for an explicit or implicit dependency to be created in the :test subproject's build.gradle on the :api subproject's openApiGenerate task.
Doing this as instructed on Gradle's documentation satisfies the error, but then it overwrites the :test build.gradle, breaking the project. I managed to resolve this issue once, but during troubleshooting it was reintroduced and the original fix doesnt work this time around. Any helpful insight on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated
Issue 02
This is the primary issue. Getting past the above issue, I then run into an issue in which the OpenAPI Generate no longer generates two files: "GsonObjectMapper.java" and "ApiClient.java". I cannot find any references to these namespaces outside the files trying to use them, and all dependencies are resolving as expected. It was generating before the updates, but doesn't now. Any insight on this, or how to properly troubleshoot it would be infinitely appreciated. Information on such behavior seems almost non-existant, and i am still relatively new to OpenAPI.
